# Directed Dependency Graph in php

Tags: graph

Is it possible to construct a directed dependency graph in Yii framework of php or in classic php. I want to dynamically draw a graph like this,

[image]

I have an array of ids as:

```
Array ( [0] =>Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 [3] => 19 )
        [1] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 18 [3] => 20 )
        [2] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 14 [3] => 21 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 18 [3] => 19 )
        [4] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 [3] => 20 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 18 [3] => 21 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 [3] => 19 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 18 [3] => 20 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 14 [3] => 21 ) 
        [9] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 18 [3] => 19 ) 
        [10] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 [3] => 20 ) 
        [11] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 18 [3] => 21 ) 
        [12] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 [3] => 19 ) 
        [13] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 18 [3] => 20 ) 
        [14] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 14 [3] => 21 ) 
        [15] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 12 [2] => 18 [3] => 19 ) 
        [16] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 13 [2] => 14 [3] => 20 ) 
        [17] => Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 16 [2] => 18 [3] => 21 ) 
    ) ;
```

Comment: Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PHP, but taking a leaf out of Maven dependency graph, you should look for a piece of code that generates a dependency tree. Because dependencies can't form a closed loop; they have to be in a tree form.